# Using SIMILAR TO together with ALL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I would like to determine if it's possible to use `SIMILAR TO` in conjunction with `ANY` or `ALL` in a PostgreSQL query.

It does for `LIKE`, i.e. I can do:

```sql
SELECT 'man bear pig' LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%fish%', '%bear%']);
```

Trying the same thing with `SIMILAR TO`:

```sql
SELECT 'man bear pig' SIMILAR TO ANY(ARRAY['%fish%', '%bear%']);
```

, which returns the error:

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "ANY"
Position: 34
```

In this case it doesn't make a big difference, but say I want to use the extended syntax e.g. `%(man|pig)%`, then `LIKE` will return a different result than `SIMILAR TO`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it directly, but you can convert it in the same way that PostgreSQL does:

```
SELECT 'man bear pig'
        ~ ANY (ARRAY[
                  similar_escape('%fish%', NULL),
                  similar_escape('%bear%', NULL)
               ]);
```

But it would be simpler to use regular expressions directly:

```
SELECT 'man bear pig'
       ~ ANY (ARRAY['fish', 'bear']);
```

Comment: Interesting.  similar_escape seems to be utterly undocumented, other than in the source code.

Comment: Well, you can easily see it using `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)`.

Comment: I see. But only if the right hand side is a column.  If it is a literal, then it gets constant folded and doesn't show you the route.

Answer (score 1):

SIMILAR TO is a bit of an odd creature.  It does not have a normal operator which it maps to (the way "LIKE" maps to "~~"), which is probably why it does not work.  Rather, it seems to be more like a macro, which gets rewritten in terms of POSIX regular expressions.

```
explain SELECT * from pgbench_accounts where filler similar to '%(fish|bear)%';
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..45517.52 rows=1 width=97)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on pgbench_accounts  (cost=0.00..44517.42 rows=1 width=97)
         Filter: (filler ~ '^(?:.*(?:fish|bear).*)$'::text)
```

See how the filter says it uses "~", and the string itself has been modified?

So one answer would be to use POSIX regular expressions in the first place, rather than SIMILAR TO.  If you don't like that, you can create your own operator:

```
create function similar_to(text, text) returns bool language SQL as $$ select $1 similar to $2 $$;
create operator ~^~ (function = similar_to, leftarg=text, rightarg=text);

SELECT 'man bear pig' ~^~ ANY(ARRAY['%fish%', '%bear%']);
```

The name '~^~' was chosen arbitrarily, you may want to put more thought into what to call it then I did.

This is probably not the most performant way to do things, and will surely defeat any index (like pg_trgm) that might otherwise be usable.